# Anti aliasing when drawing round bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, antialiasing

I would like to draw a round bitmap (transparent square 50x50 with round colorfull picture by a radius 25 in a center) with smooth edges. How can I handle that?
I tried this, but it doesn't work (edges aren't smooth):

```
Paint p =new Paint();
p.setFilterBitmap(true);
p.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), y - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), p);
```

Comment: post screenshot how you want?

Comment: try to set p.setDither(true)......does this work?

Comment: I tried, but p.setDither(true) doesn't work.

Comment: I mean all together, setFilterBitmap(),setAntiAlias() and setDither().....done this?